# How to disable 2FA for appcelerator CI builds?

Tags: appcelerator

We are trying to get CI via jenkins running for our appcelerator project. Unfortunately the CLI from time to time requires to validate via a code sent to us by email.

The support told us to "Disable 2FA on your build account" and "Run appc login before the build. You can save your credentials in a Jenkins variable, and then mask it:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin"

See also https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/CLI-996

Can someone tell me HOW to disable 2FA on the build account?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the appcelerator support team deabled 2FA for the account. So it looks like you cannot do this on your own, but have to contact the support team.